# How to calculate an average for each entire name and repeat the value?

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a table in a mysql DB that look like this:

```
Name   Val
bb     5
bb     10
kk     12
kk     8
jj     6
jj     15
```

I want to calculate the average of each name and repeat the result in line with the appropriate name like this:

```
Name  Val  Avg(Val)
bb    5     7.5
bb    10    7.5
kk    12    10
kk    8     10
jj    6     10.5
jj    15    10.5
```

I have a query statement that look as follows with "varcalc" the table name, but only works for the one specific value:

```
SELECT Name, Val, (SELECT AVG(Val) FROM varcalc WHERE name="bb") FROM varcalc
```

How can i adjust my statement so that the result look like the second table?

Comment: Why the silent downvote? At least be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Name,AVG(Val) AS Avg FROM varcalc GROUP by Name
```

This will show you the data for all the names. But in order to calculate that average, those names won't be repeated again and again. It is contrary to the logic of Average to compute those values over and over.

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48541/2/0)**

**Why should you not repeat those rows?**

Consider you have 1 million names, Any use of extra sub queries to repeat the `AVG` value will make the database compute the average again and again for no good reason. It should only compute that for once per Name. Then you can display it on your website any way you want.

Comment: What for you output `val` along with the average? With RDBMS other than MySQL such a query would fail with error. It is totally incorrect to use `val` and `avg(val)` in single select list! Which `val` will be choosed to output??

Comment: "It is contrary to the logic of Average to show those values over and over" - maybe it is contrary to the logic of avarage, but it is not contrary to the logic of, say, windowed average and other resembling operations. More powerful RDBMS, like Oracle, even have specialised variant of arrgregate functions, called [analitic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), for tasks like this. You **can not statement** that it is Jason's error to want group average column. It is useful in various tasks.

Comment: "Heard about Alias" - Yes, and what? I am not talking about column names. I am talking about **choosing** `val` from **each group** of `val`s. Have you heard about PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server and etc.? Please, try such a query there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, Val, (SELECT AVG(Val) FROM varcalc v2  WHERE v1.name=v2.name) FROM varcalc v1
```

Comment: +1 @Jason, this gives you what you asked for, but also consider something like Hanky suggested, which would be more typical.

Comment: Not just `more typical`: consider a scenario where the Average has to be calculated for a million records, do you want this sub query to repeat taking average a million times when it can calculate it in one go?

Comment: If he want to display each value for each name, is the query ok. if he want to see the name and only the average value, he should take your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` with subquery:

```
SELECT 
  varcalc.*, 
  avg_name.avg_val 
FROM 
  varcalc 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT AVG(Val) AS avg_val, Name FROM varcalc GROUP BY Name) AS avg_name 
    ON varcalc.Name=avg_name.Name
```

-so you'll get average value for each `Name` repeated for each row